# 'Amorevole' innuendo

Tags: word-usage, etymology

A modern art critic refers to a 17th century Italian painter's pupil as his 'amorevole', quotes included.

Does this imply a possibly amorous relation between the master and his disciple or does it simply say that the young man was his favorite pupil?

Comment: Could you post the complete phase? In general *amorevole* means affectionate and does not imply an amorous relation but if quotes are included *'amorevole'* may be ironic and mean *loving* or even *hateful*...

Comment: You should include more information or possibly a link to your question. Without more context we can only suggest personal opinions.

Comment: I never heard *amorevole* used explicitly as good friend, lover or catamite (it would be *amasio*, for instance), but of course one might imply such a meaning. See more shades of meaning in 1865 Tommaseo-Bellini vocabulary: https://books.google.it/books?id=bJghprhgU60C&pg=PA406&dq=%22amorevole%22&hl=it&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22amorevole%22&f=false

Comment: From the answers and comments I got, for which I'm grateful, and from looking up "suo amorevole", where amorevole is used as a noun in older texts, it appears that a deviant interpretation of the word isn't warranted in this context.

Comment: Your post isn't really an answer to the question, so I've converted it to a comment.

Answer (score 3):

I transform my comment into an answer.

Usually, *amorevole* means affectionate and does *not* imply a sexual relationship, for example:

> Una mamma è sempre amorevole verso i suoi figli.

but, if quotes are included, *'amorevole'* may be ironic and take other meanings.

For example:

> Il pittore Tizio era sempre accompagnato dal suo 'amorevole' allievo Caio.

may mean that Tizio and Caio were lovers.

Another example:

> Il capo a Tizio: "Perché mi disturbi per questa inezia? Non vedi che non ho tempo? Risolvila da solo!"
>
> Il capo a Caio: "Hai preparato la presentazione? Doveva essere pronta per ieri! Non voglio sentire scuse, sei sempre lento! La voglio sulla mia scrivania tra un'ora!"
>
> Tizio a Caio, in pausa caffè: "Oggi il capo è più 'amorevole' del solito, deve aver litigato con la moglie prima di venire in ufficio!"

In this case *amorevole* is an ironic way to say the boss is *hateful*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The sentence (from Ann Sutherland Harris's book on 17th century painter Andrea Sacchi) is : "Prospero Fidanza, Sacchi's `amorevole', is put in charge of the distribution of money to the poor of Sacchi's parish after the artist's death. His close relationship with Sacchi is also made clear by the other responsibilities he is to assume at that time. He was to look after the financial investments made on behalf of Giovanni Battista and Francesco Luti, [etc.] Nothing else is known about him."

Comment: I've never heard about 'amorevole' as a noun, it is usually used as an adjective, it may mean lover but I think there is the need of some linguist's opinion (I'm only Italian mother tongue). @DaG have you seen the complete sentence? (My eyes are not so sharp to read your link). Thank you!

Comment: I found where it comes from: the painter Andrea Sacchi's will, transcribed as "distribut(io)ne lascia che si contenti haverla il Sig(no)re Prospero Fidanza suo amorevole, ad arbitrio del quale rimette d(ett)a distribut(io)ne." As it turns out, the expression "suo amorevole", where amorevole is uses as a noun, appears elsewhere, for instance [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=UXelu7O7MvcC&pg=PA11&dq=%22suo+amorevole,+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD0farw8HOAhULpx4KHXs7BxcQ6AEIRTAF#v=onepage&q=%22suo%20amorevole%2C%20%22&f=false)

Comment: @JeanB: I think it would be a good idea to include all this information in the text of the question.

Comment: @JeanB It's an archaic term, I'm sorry but I can't help you, I hope that someone else will be able to do it. As Charo told you, complete your question and then I'll delete my answer because it is of no use for you, thank you!